# Add a different title to leaflet multi layers control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps

I have two control layers on the top left and bottom left. I want to add a title only to the control layer on the top left. I use insertBefore() is work but the title appears on both control layers. is there any solution for this problem?

this my layer control

```
var layertopleft = new L.control.layers(baseMaps1, overlayMaps, optionL).addTo(map);
var layerbotleft = new L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps1, {collapsed: false, position: "bottomright"}).addTo(map);
```

this code of add a title

```
$('<div id="mapTitle" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16pt">Peta Bantuan Pemerintah</span></br><span style="font-size:12pt">Dinas Ketahanan Pangan Provinsi Riau</span></div><hr>').insertBefore('.leaflet-control-layers-base');
```

this a result

I want the title on the bottom left control layer do not exist:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I got the answer for my problem

by add `+` on selector and using `children()`, I don't know if this is the best way but it looks fine to me

```
$(".leaflet-top" + ".leaflet-right").children().prepend('<div id="mapTitle" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size:16pt">Peta Bantuan Pemerintah</span></br><span style="font-size:12pt">Dinas Ketahanan Pangan Provinsi Riau</span></div><hr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you could select both of those spans and then do your insert on the span that you want the title on.

```
$(".leaflet-control-layers-base'").each( function() {
   // $(this) decide when to insert your title
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work for me. the title still appears on both control layers. that happens because the classes used in both control layers are the same.